# How to bind enum to text block

Tags: wpf

I'm implementing a keyboard trainer. For dispaying the keys I use TexBlock (other elements are not suitable for task). How can I bind the value of enum System.Windows.Input.Key to the tag of this TexBlock?

Comment: I'll send you code showing you how to bind the enum to the ```TextBlock``` but I'm not sure why you'd want to bind it to the ```Tag``` and I'm not sure how you'd want the display to look.  This question is straight forward but in the world of UI some layout logic would help as the answer may be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer; take what you need from it however you want.

There are a few things in this example that will help you along. I'll include the whole `MainWindow.xaml` to view at the end but will break it up and explain here.

First you need to have a reference to the proper namespaces in your view.

```
xmlns:WindowsInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Input;assembly=WindowsBase"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then make an `ObjectDataProvider` which is used to call methods on types and much more.  You'll see how it works here but I recommend reading more about it because this isn't all it's meant for.  However; in this example you'll see it references the method name and type we want to call and allows us to pass in the parameters to the method as well.  This let's us do it all in xaml rather than code behind; which to me is much nicer.  The idea isn't just to have it here in your view like it is but for simplicity...

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="GetKeyNames"
                    MethodName="GetNames"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="WindowsInput:Key" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Finally I bind that to an `ItemsSource`.  It will call the method and return the values as data.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetKeyNames}}">
```

This requires more explanation but given this tid bit and the full `MainWindow.xaml` below I believe you'll get the picture and see the answer to your question.  If you need more explanation I'll happily update the answer.

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:WindowsInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Input;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="GetKeyNames"
                            MethodName="GetNames"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="WindowsInput:Key" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetKeyNames}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Green"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Width="100"
                            Height="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

This example looks something like this:

[image]